# how to display only one country in magento website?

Tags: magento

I want to filter only one country in country dropdown of the checkout process in my website.
How can i do this.

can anyone please suggest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

that's your shipping process.

Depending in what shipping extension you are using, select the country you allow the user to ship.

```
System > Configuration > Shipping Methods > Ship to Specific Countries
```

[image]

if you want to allow only certain countries to be available, you can also set that up the same way, but now using:

```
System > Configuration > General > Countries Options
```

[image]

Comment: I did this but still all the countries are showing.I think i have to apply some filter over in the code. but how?

Comment: if you already setup correctly, but you still getting the old configuration, you need to refresh Magento cache, or manually empty the `/var/cache`...

Comment: I am not using any shipping extension. Simply I want that country dropdown in checkout process should display only one country in its dropdown list in frontend.

Comment: Sure you are! At least an Extension from Magento itself, "Flat Rate", "Free Shipping", etc ... these are all "Shipping Extensions". You might also change your **General** settings. I have updated my answer to include it.

Comment: Hey balexandre !! Thank you very much.It's a Time Zone problem.Now it is solved.

Comment: Thanks dear..But I want to do this by changing code in the file.But i am confused to where should i change the code.I found out that after applying filters to getCountryCollection() method ,we can achieve this.But this method is present in data.php , Onepage.php , Abstract.php and others also.So where should i change??  ..Please correct me if i am wrong..Thanks

Comment: Set the two things mentioned in the first post. They are multi select so make sure the only highlighted item is your chosen country. After doing this, clear your cache and recompile to make sure the settings take. Don't make a hard solution for an easy answer, too many people think because they have the source code that it's an immediate code rewrite for most solutions. You will hate yourself for doing this in the future. His solution must work, I did exactly the same thing two years ago and can't find anything I've excluded via this method.

Comment: And change the **Ship to Applicable Countries** dropdown to **Specific Countries** in any Shipping Method you choose to use in System Config so only your highlighted items in the **Ship to Specific Countries** multiselect are available.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple:
Go to System > Configuration > General > Countries Options
under 'Allow Countries', select those countries which you want to be present in the dropdown at checkout

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but I wanted to show 3 different countries only on cart and checkout page. For that I have searched many things, finally I removed 
using jQuery.

```
jQuery("#shipping-zip-form #country option").each(function()
{
    if (jQuery(this).val()!='US' && jQuery(this).val()!='CA' && jQuery(this).val()!='PR' && jQuery(this).val()!='') {
        jQuery("#shipping-zip-form #country option[value='"+jQuery(this).val()+"']").remove();
    }
});
```